# issues with abbr tag in php array. only shows until first space

Tags: php, tags

i am trying to incorporate the abbr tag into my php array, so that when an abbreviation for an airport, such as MSP or AMS shows up, when you hover over it it will show the full name of the airport.

the code that I am using is:

```
echo "    <td width='70' bgcolor='$row_color'><img src='../flags/".$row['countryflag']."'>   
&nbsp;&nbsp;<abbr title=".$row['luchthavennaam'].">".$row['luchthavencode']."</abbr></td>";
```

It will show me up until the first space in the name of it and then cuts it off. When i run my query in Toad, I do see the full name show up, so it's something with how I'm working this.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add quotes: `<abbr title=\"". htmlspecialchars($row['luchthavennaam'])."\">`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "<td width='70' bgcolor='$row_color'><img src='../flags/".$row['countryflag']."'>   
&nbsp;&nbsp;<abbr title='".$row['luchthavennaam']."'>".$row['luchthavencode']."</abbr>   </td>";
```

You were missing the single quotes in the title.

Notice

`title='".$row['luchthavennaam']."'`

instead of

`title=".$row['luchthavennaam']."`.

Comment: thank you. that also makes sense. i'm very new still to this coding language and was quite impressed i was able to even get that far ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd prefer using single quotes with php

```
echo '<td width="70" bgcolor="'.$row_color.'"><img src="../flags/'.$row['countryflag'].'">   
&nbsp;&nbsp;<abbr title="'.$row['luchthavennaam'].'">'.$row['luchthavencode'].'</abbr></td>';
```